# How to find XPath in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: xpath

I have installed Firefox Developer Edition. How to find XPath in this browser? I would like to get XPath and use in Selenium script.

Comment: I get that it's not an optimal phrasing of this question, but it sure had the right google juice to get me [the answer I was seeking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56332170/785213).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right-click on any element on the page. Select ‘Inspect Element’ in the pop-up menu.
Right click on the tag in Inspector and select ‘Copy’ from pop-up & choose XPath.
Paste the XPath wherever required.

Comment: Works on Chrome as well

Answer (score 8):

### $x(path, [startNode])

`$x(path)` returns an array of DOM elements that match the given XPath expression.

For example, the following returns all the `<p>` elements on the page:

```
 $x("//p")
```

[image: browser javascript console]

The following example returns all the `<p>` elements that contain `<a>` elements:

```
$x("//p[a]")
```

[image: browser javascript console]

Similar to the other selector functions, `$x(path)` has an optional second parameter, startNode, that specifies an element or Node from which to search for elements.

[image: browser javascript console]

Comment: Just based on the accepted answer, this doesn't answer the question originally asked (but how could you have known, really, the way it's worded). However, it's still a **great** answer, and it exactly answers the question _I_ had. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly there is no need of installing Add-ons in firefox developer edition, coz it's already packed with tools and all...

Now for Xpath:

Select any element by right click on it and choose Inspect Element(Q) then element/tag gets highlighted under inspector developer tool,
(or you can open console by pressing F12 button).

Then Right Click on tag and select Copy=>Xpath,
 it will copy the Xpath of that element and then you can paste it on your script or notepad whatever you like..

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It will work for Selector, CSSSelector, Absolute XPath, Relative Xpath

Firefox : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chropath-for-firefox/

Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo